# Relationship between Dockerfile EXPOSE and Kubernetes service/container ports?

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I was under the impression in Kubernetes the way you expose a port for your application was by first exposing it in the Dockerfile using `EXPOSE`, then setting the `containerPort` setting in the deployment yaml file, and finally setting the `targetPort` in the service yaml file. I thought these all had to be the same value e.g. `7214`.

However I've just noticed that I've had the incorrect port exposed in one my applications Dockerfile as `7124` (but have the correct port in the other two files) like so :

**Dockerfile**

```
expose 7124 #This is incorrect
```

**Deployment.yaml**

```
ports:
  - containerPort: 7214
```

**Service.yaml**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
 name: my-service
spec:
 type: NodePort
 ports:
  - port: 7214
    targetPort: 7214
```

However my other applications are hitting the service fine and the requests are being forwarded onto the application at port `7214` without issue.

Why is this working? Is it not required for me to expose the port in the Dockerfile at all? Does `containerPort` take precedence or something? [This users](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57565261/3275784) answer on a similar question says the exposed port doesn't have to match, but doesn't explain why.

Comment: That is because you are saying `expose 7124` I want to expose all the traffic to my app on port 7124

Comment: Sure I understand that. But that doesn't explain why my other apps are then able to access it on port `7214`? `7214` is not exposed from the Dockerfile, so why can it be accessed?

Comment: `containerPort: 7214` overwrites the dockerfile port...you can see the same behavior with ENV variables for example....add some env variables on the dockerfile, and then define the same vars with other values on the yaml file and you should see them with the new value instaead of the dockerfile value.

Comment: Ok right that's what I suspected but just wanted to confirm! Thank you! So is there no point in exposing anything in the Dockerfile then in that case?

Answer (score 7):

The port on which a process is listening is only known to the developer of the process as the port binding happens in code. `EXPOSE` and `containerPort` are ways to communicate this to outside world.

`EXPOSE` directive in the Dockerfile doesn't do anything other than acting as documentation for the person reading your dockerfile to understand which port the process in the container might be listening on and for some UI purpose when you run `docker ps` command. It's like a communication between the author of the dockerfile and another person who might be using your image or modifyng your dockerfile.

Even the `containerPort` section in your deployment.yaml has no affect on anything. It also acts as documentation for people reading your manifest to know on which ports your process within the pod might be listening on. Another use is that you can give a name to the port using the `name` field and then you can reference this port by name in other places like the service object.

The only thing that matters is the actual port that your process is listening on in the container and making sure that port is used in `targetPort` field in the service port.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm still a bit confused. So if I didn't have a service sitting in front of my pod, how would the port be exposed then? Say I wanted to communicate directly to the pod on port `7214` from within the cluster using another app. From your wording I can't understand if the port is always exposed or never, because things like `expose` and `containerPort` are ignored. Could you clarify this?

Comment: You can always talk to pod on the pod-host-name:7214 or pod-ip:7214 from within the cluster. But pods are ephemeral as they can move between nodes incase of eviction due to node unavailability or resource crunch and so the pod names and pod IPs can keep changing.  pod names also have random characters in them. Using a service object, you can access the backend pod using the service name of your liking. When you create a service object, it just programs the iptables such that any request on the serviceIp:port is forwarded to any of the backing pod-ip:targetPort.

Comment: Yes I understand services are the way to go because the pod are ephemeral. I was just under the impression that the ports weren't accessible by default until you exposed them? Because I thought by default docker containers don't expose their ports until you use the `--publish` flag. Is this not the case with Kubernetes as well? Because unless I'm misunderstanding, it sounds to me like the ports are exposed by default if I can just access it directly on the pod?

Comment: When you use the `--publish` flag with docker, you are actually binding the container port with a port on the host network. That is not what happens with pods. The ports are not bound on host network but on the pod network i.e., pod-ip:port. Equivalent behavior of `--publish` with pods would be to use `hostPort` field.

Answer (score 7):

The `EXPOSE` option in a Dockerfile serves merely as a documentation, it is **not exposing** the port as stated by the [official documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#expose):

> The EXPOSE instruction does not actually publish the port. It functions as a type of documentation between the person who builds the image and the person who runs the container, about which ports are intended to be published.

In Kubernetes the equivalent to `EXPOSE` is `spec.containers.ports.containerPort`. You can set both values to whatever you want and it will not change anything at all. Think of it as a comment.

With a `Service` object it is a little bit different, there the values do matter. A `Service` takes `spec.ports.port` and `spec.ports.targetPort`.
If you don't specify the `targetPort` then Kubernetes will set its value to the same as specified in `port` (which is required).

However, it is not necessary for `targetPort` and `port to be the same, in fact they do have different purposes:

- `port` specifies the port of the `Service`
- `targetPort` specifies the port of the `Pod`

So the general flow looks something like this:

`call to <service-name>:port` -> forwards to a Pod with label `foo: bar` -> Pod receives the call on `targetPort`

Here is an example:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: MyApp
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 12345
```

Resulting in:

`curl my-service:80` -> forwards to a Pod with label `app: MyApp` -> Pod receives the request on `12345`.

In your case you communicate with your Service on port `7214` and it forwards the request to the Pod also to port `7214`, that's why it will continue to work no matter what you set for `EXPOSE` or `containerPort`.

Comment: I appreciate the link to and quote of the documentation backing up the answer.